# How can I fit 2d grid in Orthographic Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I create random sized 2d grids and set the camera to middle of the grid, I also try to understand orthographic size and adjust it to fit whole grid but I guess I fail, Here are the code snippet and the fitting problem:

I would also be appreciated if you have any other advice for my programming and design style.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.WSA;

public class Grid2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _width, _height;
    [SerializeField] private Tile  _tilePrefap;
    [SerializeField] private  Camera _cam;

    void Start()
    {

        GenerarteGrid();
        SetCamera(_width,_height);

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void GenerarteGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _height; j++)
            {
                var tile = Instantiate(_tilePrefap, new Vector3(i, j, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                tile.transform.parent = transform;
                tile.name = j + " " + i;

            }
        }
    }



    private void SetCamera(int x, int y)
    {
        _cam.orthographicSize = (float) _height / 2 + 0.5f ;

        _cam.transform.position = new Vector3((float)x / 2 - 0.5f, (float)y / 2 - 0.5f, 0);
    }


}
```

[image: fit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check whether to match the height or width like e.g.

```
_cam.orthographicSize = width > height ? width / camera.aspect / 2f : height / 2f;
// optional space
_cam.orthographicSize += 0.5f;
```